# Angular Forms - Submit button of the "last" form does not work

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, form-submit

I have a very simple **Angular Form**. Its **submit button** does no do anything when clicked. But when I duplicate the form, the submit button of the **first form works**. But the **last form's submit button doesn't**. Can someone tell me how to fix this ?

this is my function in the component

```
  message : String;

  sendMessage() {
      console.log("button clicked !");
  }
```

my template is

```
<form (ngSubmit)="sendMessage()" >
    <textarea class="form-control" name="MyMessage" [(ngModel)]="message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="register"  >Send Message</button>
</form>
<!-- the second form is needed to get the first ones submit button to work -->
<form (ngSubmit)="sendMessage()" >
    <textarea class="form-control" name="MyMessage" [(ngModel)]="message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

When I have multiple forms, all submit buttons work except the the last ones submit button.

Appreciate your help !

Comment: there is no problem with your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hutpaj .
try to reproduce it.

Comment: instead of `(ngSubmit)`, try using `(submit)`

Comment: No luck so far. @FatemeFazli I too think that the code is fine. It's more like a bug in the framework, or maybe a dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the culprit. I had a footer component in my page

```
<footer class="footer">
  <p  class="text-xs-center">My footer</p>
</footer>
```

It was covering the submit button. Because of this when I click on the submit button it wouldn't actually get clicked. There was no problem with the code. Thanks a lot everybody for trying to help. Really appreciate it :).

Answer (score 1):

this wont work as u have not intialized formGroup.

try using forms to perform the same action.

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="sendMessage(messageForm.value)" [formGroup]="messageForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="message"
                                    class="form-control"/>
    <button class="btn btn-normal btn-white" type="submit"
                                [disabled]="messageForm.invalid">Continue</button>
 </form>
```

.ts

```
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

....
constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder);


....
this.messageForm = this._fb.group({
  message: [null, [Validators.required],
});
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but it didn't work :( . When I duplicate your form, the first submit button works but the last button doesn't. It doesn't look like it's a problem with the code. Maybe some bug in a dependency ? Thanks